# Get ID of record when mysql returns duplicate error

Tags: php, mysql

Is there a way to retrieve the ID of a record (primary key) after an insert when the mysql error returns a duplicate key?

E.G. How I would go about it:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO table (`col1`, `col2`) VALUES ('$val1', '$val2')";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
if($result){
  $id = mysql_insert_id();
}
else {
  if(stristr(mysql_error(), "duplicate"){
    $sql = "SELECT `id` FROM `table` WHERE `col1`='$val1' AND `col2`='$val2'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    $id = $row['id'];
  }
  else {
    die(mysql_error());
  }
}
```

Here I've had to do two sql statements which not only take time and effort, but duplicate code as well.

I cannot use `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` because I want to update a different table using the either the last inserted id, or the id of the record that cannot be duplicated.

So, am I right in what I'm doing? Or is there a way to get the id of the row?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

MySQL will not tell you which record holds the original value, you'll have to find out yourself. Here you are some tips:

- Looking for the `duplicate` substring in the text of the error message does not look very robust. You can just test the value of mysql_errno() against the code for duplicate entry, which is [1062](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-errors/8.0/en/server-error-reference.html#error_er_dup_entry) ([you can find all codes in the manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-errors/8.0/en/server-error-reference.html#error_er_dup_entry)).
- The mysql extension does not provide a mechanism to find out name of the violated key, so you'll have to use the non-robust approach of parsing the text of the error message:

  ```
    if( preg_match("/Duplicate entry '.*' for key '(.*)'/Ui", mysql_error(), $matches) ){
        $violated_key = $matches[1];
    }else{
        throw new Exception('Could not find violated key name');
    }
  ```
- Alternatively, just run a previous query (there's no reason to avoid it):

  ```
    SELECT id
    FROM table
    WHERE col1=... AND col2=...
    FOR UPDATE
  ```

  The `FOR UPDATE` clause will lock matching rows to avoid race conditions (assuming InnoDB).

Comment: Glad it helped. Let me add a note: obviously, `FOR UPDATE` will lock nothing if there aren't matches. You can still get the record created by other concurrent process just after the check. Just take that into account.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'm not using InnoDB, and never have, so I'm not sure what you're talking about! :p But I shall look into it. :)