# get the primary key after a DUPLICATE KEY error?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

If I run an insert query but it fails because of duplicated key error is there any way to get its primary key without doing another select?

Basically:

```
INSERT INTO tbl (field) VALUES ('myvalue')
```

This fails because there is already a record with ID:1 and field:myvalue.

Now I Want to know that ID:1 without doing another query:

```
SELECT id FROM tbl WHERE field = 'myvalue'
```

is it possibile?

Comment: How do you get the `ID:1` value? is it the default value? Shouldn't you have `AUTO_INCREMENT`?

Comment: You may have anonymized the SQL too much. I don't see how the first query would ever cause a primary key error unless `field` (instead of `id`) was the field which was keyed.

Comment: field is UNIQUE, and of course is an example like ID:X

Comment: I doubt there's a way. *Generally*, SQL is a set-oriented language. To be thorough, if there *were* such a way, it ought to return *all* of the rows which violate one or more of the constraints on the table. But in order to compute that set, it would have to continue a set of potentially very expensive operations, for an operation that it knows it's going to roll back anyway - and for which many people aren't going to ask for that information. (And there may be dependencies between rows which would give false constraint violations also)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get ID of record when mysql returns duplicate error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9094605/get-id-of-record-when-mysql-returns-duplicate-error)

Comment: yea looking for the mysql error could be a good solution, problem is that string doenst' contain PRIMARY KEY just the UNIQUE keys that threw error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a link that provides four different ways to deal with this:
http://mikefenwick.com/blog/insert-into-database-or-return-id-of-duplicate-row-in-mysql/

Answer (score 0):

There is a provision with each library to get the id of the row which is inserted.

Like: for simple `mysql_query()` use `mysql_insert_id()` after that to retrive the id of the last inserted row

[Check this link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php)

EDIT:

Please Check that if you have defined the unique index for `field` column.

If yes then you cannot insert duplicate in the column `field`

Comment: mysql_insert_id works only if the query is successfully inserted, according to OP's question, the query insert failed

Comment: mysql_insert_id doenst' work when there is a duplicate key error

Comment: But how could the query fail???? he is not providing the ID so that it will give duplicate field error.